# Remove nested class from an element JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have some nested elements, how would I remove the class name of one that is nested deep with pure JavaScript?

For example:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="a">
  <div class="b">
   <div class="c">
    // Remove class name only of below element
    <div class="remove-me">Remove class name only of this element</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to do this in pure JavaScript

Comment: Your post is confusing.
Are you trying to remove the class-name, or the element itself?

Comment: I would like to remove class name

Comment: `document.querySelector('.wrapper .remove-me').classList.remove('remove-me');`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `elem.classList.remove("remove-me");`.

example to select element:

```
let elem = document.querySelector('.wrapper>.a>.b>.c>.remove-me');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do it by directly getting and modifying this element? For example like this:

```js
let element = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-me')[0];
console.log(element.classList); //here you can see this element classes
element.classList.remove('remove-me');
console.log(element.classList); //here you can see that we removed one
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="a">
  <div class="b">
   <div class="c">
    // Remove class of below element
    <div class="remove-me">Remove class of this element</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a better practice to select elements by an `id`.
But if all you have to go by is the `class-name` it can still be done fairly easily.
You can select the element using said `class-name`, and remove it using some built-in JS methods.

Selecting the element looks like this:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.remove-me');
```

Then removing the class-name can look like this,
which can be convinient if you have only a single class:

```js
element.className = '';
```

Or like this if you have more:

```js
element.classList.remove('remove-me');
```